# How to create print queue for Epson Impact Printer in iOS?

Tags: ios, printing, epson

I am working with hardware integration and there is a need of printer integration for my app.

Our app is using Epson TM-U220 Impact printer.

There are so many ipads start printing at same time on a single printer.
Can any one suggest me how to manage print queue so app can not miss any ticket to print and can not print duplicate print ?

We are using Core data to track printed or error print jobs.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Unless you want to route all print jobs through one iOS device you will need to rely on the printer to separate jobs.  I would assume that the printer is capable of holding other jobs until it has finished the current one.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for reply. Printer can print one job at a time and it can not hold other jobs. We are sending jobs one by one. It will give error message when other print job is already processing.

Comment: Then you either need to keep retrying or you will need to designate one device to be a print master (or hold an election; this way you can reconfigure If the current master "goes away") and have all other devices send their job details to the master and have it talk to the printer